# can't get testcontainers Kafka with sasl.jaas.config to test ACLs to work

Tags: testing, apache-kafka, acl, sasl, testcontainers

I'm trying to leverage [testcontainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java) to test Kafka locally in some automated unit tests. I'm having trouble testing authorization.

My goal is to test

(1) if there are no ACLs in this test container that no `KafkaProducer` should be allowed to write to it (currently, even with no ACLs created as long as a producer is configured correctly, it can send to the topic - I thought setting the kafka env variable of `allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found` to false would do the trick - but doesn't seem to be the case)

(2) to test if the `KafkaProducer` is not using the correct `sasl.jaas.config` (i.e incorrect apiKey and pasword) that it gets denied access to write to the test topic, even if an ACL is setup for all principals.

Below is my code. I can get it to "work" but testing the above two scenarios I haven't been able to figure out. I think I might not be actually creating ACLs, as when I add a line after I create the ACLs (`adminClient.describeAcls(AclBindingFilter.ANY).values().get();` I get a `No Authorizer is configured on the broker` error) -> looking at posts similar to [this](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-tools-kafka-acls.html) I thought this implies that no ACL binding had actually been created.

```
import org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.Network;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.acl.AccessControlEntry;
import org.apache.kafka.common.acl.AclBinding;
import org.apache.kafka.common.acl.AclOperation;
import org.apache.kafka.common.acl.AclPermissionType;
import org.apache.kafka.common.resource.PatternType;
import org.apache.kafka.common.resource.ResourcePattern;
import org.apache.kafka.common.resource.ResourceType;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

        String topicName = "this-is-a-topic";
        String confluentVersion = "5.5.1";
        network = Network.newNetwork();
        String jaasTemplate = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required %s=\"%s\" %s=\"%s\";";
        String jaasConfig = String.format(jaasTemplate, "username", "apiKey", "password", "apiPassword");
        kafka = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:" + confluentVersion))
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withEnv("KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE", "false")
                .withEnv("KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND", "false")
                .withEnv("KAFKA_SUPER_USERS", "User:OnlySuperUser")
                .withEnv("KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM", "PLAIN")
                .withEnv("KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM", "http")
                .withEnv("KAFKA_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG", jaasConfig);

        kafka.start();
        schemaRegistryContainer = new SchemaRegistryContainer(confluentVersion).withKafka(kafka);
        schemaRegistryContainer.start();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafka.getBootstrapServers());
        properties.put("input.topic.name", topicName);
        properties.put("input.topic.partitions", "1");
        adminClient = KafkaAdminClient.create(properties);
        AclBinding ACL = new AclBinding(new ResourcePattern(ResourceType.TOPIC, topicName, PatternType.LITERAL),
                new AccessControlEntry( "User:*", "*", AclOperation.WRITE, AclPermissionType.ALLOW));
        var acls = adminClient.createAcls(List.of(ACL)).values();


        List<NewTopic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
        topics.add(
                new NewTopic(topicName,
                        Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("input.topic.partitions")),
                        Short.parseShort(properties.getProperty("input.topic.replication.factor")))
        );
        adminClient.createTopics(topics);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

        props.put("input.topic.name", topicName);
        props.put("security.protocol", "PLAINTEXT");
        props.put("input.topic.partitions", "1");
        props.put("input.topic.replication.factor", "1");
        props.put("metadata.fetch.timeout.ms", "10000");
        props.put("sasl.jaas.config", jaasConfig);

        producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

        String key = "testContainers";
        String value = "AreAwesome";
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(
                        (String) props.get("input.topic.name"), key, value);
        try {
             RecordMetadata o = (RecordMetadata) producer.send(record).get();
             System.out.println(o.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Seem to be having issues getting the SASL_MECHANISM to be recognized at all

Comment: ya - that's what I was running into as well - haven't had time to find a solution. but if I do - I will post, please post if you find one as well :)

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Comment: Hi @hhprogram, if you don't mind i tap on your knowledge/experience, did you have to copy any `jaas` file in the container, using `withCopyFileToContainer` for example, `kafka_server_jaas.conf`? Because with just setting the `withEnv`, i can't get it to work(which makes sense). Thanks.

Comment: @jumping_monkey I didn't try actually creating a jaas file in the container, what you see above, is mostly what I did. It could be that I needed to create an actual jaas file in the test container, but I'm not sure - interested if you get it to work